# Uninstalling Canopy Enthought leaves strange bash warning?

Tags: python, macos, bash, enthought

So I uninstalled `Enthought Canopy` (I think completely, but I'm unsure if there's residual information hanging around that I neglected to modify).

After uninstalling, following the directions here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy

I was slightly unsettled by the fact that I couldn't find anything to delete for step 5, and since Canopy was never my default `Python` environment, I didn't think too much of it.

But now, every time I open terminal, I get this warning:

```
"-bash: /Users/MyName/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate: No such file or directory"
```

What do I need to do to fix this? I'm running `Mac OSX, 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion)`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe unthought modifies your bash_profile file. What are the contents of that file under your home directory?

Comment: There's nothing in there. :(

Comment: @deepak: Actually, `.bash_profile` doesn't make sense for this, as it's only run on login shells, not on child-process shells within the same interactive session; works great for updating environment variables, but not so much for shell functions -- and the `activate` script defines a shell-function `deactivate`, so it wouldn't work properly if sourced from `.bash_profile`. More likely is `.bashrc`.

Comment: In Mac OS X, all new terminal windows start login shells by default, as the terminal emulator itself was not started from a login shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until today I had this exact same problem, and it really bothered me. I solved it this way:

First, I entered following command in the terminal: `open -a TextEdit .bash_profile`
This opens your `.bash_profile` in TextEdit, which for a terminal novice like me at least, is easier than editing it in the terminal with vi or something like that. In that file, you should see a few lines related to "Canopy" and "Enthought". In my case, this is what showed up:

```
# Added by Canopy installer on 2014-02-11
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active,       otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source /Users/MyUserame/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

I think it is that last line that is causing all the trouble. Simply delete these few lines (don't delete anything else). In my case, these lines were in a separate block from others in my .bash_profile so it was easy to pick them out. After this, just close the text file, restart your computer, and the annoying stuff about Enthought not being found should be gone. For me this worked, hope it does for you too!

Comment: A full restart shouldn't be necessary for this to take effect -- remove the lines, and it should be effective the immediate next time a Terminal window or other shell is opened.

Comment: One other quibble -- there should be a space between `source` and `/Users`; otherwise, this wouldn't work even when Canopy was correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing space! Also, I didn't think the restart would be necessary, but that advice came directly from the Enthought support file. I didn't try it before the restart.

Comment: Unfortunately, it says I don't have a bash_profile? 
The exact output I get is: "The file /Users/MyName/.bash_profile does not exist."

Comment: Maybe try the same command but with `.profile` instead of `.bash_profile`:`open -a TextEdit .profile`

Comment: This might be helpful too, if you haven't seen it already: https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-Canopy

Comment: elethan, I already used that link to try to uninsstall the first time, but I did find the lines Canopy Installer added in the .profile! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To find out where this is, run an interactive shell with the `xtracefd` flag set and a `PS4` that includes `$BASH_SOURCE`. For instance:

```
PS4='+$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO:' bash -i -x
```

Then, look through the output for the first reference to the `activate` script given; it will include the source file and line number.

Most likely, this will be `.bashrc`.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you, but when I run this line in my terminal, I end up running from "bash-3.2"? Is that line 3 in .bashrc or what does that mean?

Comment: There should be rather a lot of other output before it gets to that point. Look through that other output -- somewhere in it will be the error message; see exactly what is before and after the error.

Comment: You don't even get the `activate: No such file or directory` message in this case? Curious; I can't reproduce that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is having this problem as I did, I found the source in my .profile file. You will see a command at the top of your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` that reads: `[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile`.  This is calling yet another script called `.profile` that you need to clean up. To edit `.profile` use the command:

```
open -a TextEdit .profile
```

Then you'll find a line in there that says something like:

```
# Added by Canopy installer on 2013-04-10
source /Users/username/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

Delete those lines and save, et voila!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error message.  You need to comment out (#) or delete the last line thats under the #Canopy settings in your bash profile.  follow below steps in terminal to get rid of the error message:

```
vim .profile
```

You should see the following info regarding your Canopy set up:

```
# Added by Canopy installer on 2016-01-12
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is active, otherwise 1
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source '/Users/waismoradi/Documents/CanopyEnthought/User/bin/activate'
```

Just delete or comment out with -> # the last line and you are all set!  This will disable the env prompt to show up when you launch terminal.